# Can anyone tell me where to find/dig in order to find: gold, diamond etc.. in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m asking this because, I want to know where to dig in order to find precious metals and stones.

**Q-1:** Do they regenerate?

**Q-2:** Where to look for precious materials?

Because, I want to find cool, diamond, gold etc... and to know whether they regenerate or not so that I can be near to them. Because now, it’s hard for me to find precious metals and diamond in Minecraft. I mean, when I find gold on a rock somewhere and by mistake I lost them, then I must find another place to look for it.

Comment: How would they regenerate? Image you build your base underground, should they just keep blocking your entrance?

Comment: @Fabian No, but I meant on rare material things such as gold and diamond. I always thought that they can regenerate.

Comment: How? What would you expect them to do? Just magically appear again in the stone? What if you dug away the stone? Should they randomly appear in mid-air?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*preface - y-leves are how many blocks above the void you are - and you can find a value for it in your F3 menu (the one you get by pressing F3)*)

[Gold](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gold_Ore) is found between y levels 2 to 29 (approximately).

[Diamonds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Ore) are found below y level 16 (and most commonly between layers 5-12).

No ore, or block in the game will "regenerate" (although trees and crops "grow") itself over time, so once you've mined an area out it will stay that way.

When it comes to mining diamonds, only 1 vein will spawn per chunk (unless it's eaten by a pre-world generation structure, like a dungeon or mineshaft).

Comment: You could improve this answer by telling us how "y levels" are counted and how you find out on which "y level" you are.

Comment: Diamonds (and other ores) are not more likely to be found at lava lakes. Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H7QDUWjHI4

Comment: *The highest concentration of diamonds occurs in levels 5-12*. [Source](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Diamond_Ore)

Answer (score 0):

The "Mountains" Biome has emerald ore and no other place does (besides trading with villagers). In "Badlands" and "Eroded Badlands" There is more Gold ore and at a higher Y level than 32. you can check if you are in these locations by hitting f3 and looking at the name beside "biome:".

Answer (score -1):

1. No, they do not regenerate.
2. They are underground.

Make a pickaxe and dig down.  Be careful of lava, don't dig straight down. Generally digging a staircase is safer as you will not fall into a lava lake and can run backwards if you dig into lava.

From the wiki on mining about [choosing which layer to mine](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Mining):

> - Levels <5: [bedrock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock)
> - Levels <30 [lava](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lava), although Lava has been found elsewhere.
> - Levels <14-5 [diamond](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Ore) and [redstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Ore)
> - Levels <30 [gold](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gold_Ore) and [lapis lazuli](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_Ore)
> - Levels <60 [iron](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ore)
> - Levels <70 [coal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coal_Ore)
> - Gravel generates between layers 1 and 111.
> - Note: If you are in a [mesa](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Mesa) biome, you would want to look for gold near the surface.
>   Due to being the safest layers to mine where all [ores](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ore) exist in reasonable quantities (especially diamond), Y-coordinates 10 to 15 are usually considered the best area in which to start mining. The single best layer for mining is highly debated and is not agreed on. Using the [debug screen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_screen) (F3) is the easiest way to find your altitude.

Use the debug screen accessed by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> to determine your current Y level when you are mining.

Here is the top left corner with the debug screen showing Y level of 73:
[image: Corner]

Comment: In gold dimension is the same? I mean, neither there the gold does not regenerate?

Comment: If you carefully build a device with water and lava, you can generate cobblestone and/or stone.  That is the only stone that "regenerates" to my knowledge.  If you are concerned of regeneration for fear of running out of these materials, you will not.  You would just have to expand your mining.

Answer (score -3):

Well it all depends on which type you are on. iIf you are in a part where you can't check your Y level, then check near lava. I found it there sometimes.